# The data property "article" is already declared as a prop. Use prop default value instead

Tags: vuejs2

Code:

```js
export default {
    props: {
        article: {type: Object}
    },
    data () {
        return {article: this.article}
    }, 
    methods: {
        itemClick () {
            console.log('itemClick');
        }
    }
};
```

Vue2.1.10 warning in Chrome developers tools: [The data property "article" is already declared as a prop. Use prop default value instead.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zyf0.png)

Comment: export default {
    props: {
      article: {
        type: Object
      }
    },
    data () {
      return {
        article: this.article
      }
    },
    methods: {
      itemClick () {
        console.log('itemClick');
      }
    }
  };

Answer (score 43):

You have added `article` at both places `data` and `props`. It should be one of these, thats why you are getting the error. You have to remove it one of the place, if you are passing it from parent component, then keep  it as props. If this is a local instance data, keep it in vue `data` block.

```
export default {
  props: {
    article: {
      type: Object
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      article: this.article
    }
  },
  methods: {
    itemClick() {
      console.log('itemClick');
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: I'm confused by your code, because it looks the same as the example from the OP.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @codeMonkey I also dont remember now, what I was thinking when writing the answer, code seems same as in question, however I see question was edited later and code was added. Also solution is explained in those three lines before code. Hope that helps.

Comment: why is this the most upvoted, it doesnt solve anything

Comment: @Saurabh, could you please fix the answer, is very confusing

Comment: Mixins could also introduce data properties that conflict with props with the same name.

Comment: You have added article at both places data and props. It should be one of these, thats why you are getting the error. You have to remove it one of the place, if you are passing it from parent component, then keep it as props. If this is a local instance data, keep it in vue data block. these lines solve the problem

Answer (score 14):

Once you declare `article` in props, you do not need to return it in side data. See below.

```
export default {
  props: {
    article: {type: Object}
  },

  data () {}, 

  methods: {
    itemClick () {
      console.log('itemClick');
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Assuming you want to mutate the prop, doing this will result in a `Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value.` error.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using TypeScript then you might have assigned a value to prop.

```
@Component
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  @Prop({ type: Array }) users = []; // wrong, do not assign to a prop
}
```

Change to this

```
...
@Prop({ type: Array }) users;
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The error message in this case was pretty confusing for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is a conflict between the **property** and the **data**. You can only have one or the other, not both:

```
export default {
    props: {
        article: {type: Object}
    },
    methods: {
        itemClick () {
            console.log('itemClick');
        }
    }
};
```

From there you can use the property **article** as if it were a data in your template. For instance:

```
template: "<div>{{ article.type.something }}</div>"
```